# separar dos palabras pegadas en JS?

Tags: javascript

quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de separar dos palabras pegadas en js, por ejemplo: `&nbsp;hola` quisiera que eso quedara `&nbsp; hola`, y luego de separarlas alguna forma de que `&nbsp;` se sustituido por `<span style = 'color:black'>&nbsp;</span>`? utilice splice(' '), pero al tener `&nbsp;hola` este lo toma como una sola palabra y no la separa

Comment: ¿Cuál es el criterio para separarlas o por que caracter se deben separar?

Comment: si delante de cierta palabra esta ```&nbsp;``` quiera sustituir eso por ```<span style = 'color: black'>&nbsp;</span>```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar esto:

```js
const text = "&nbsp;hola";
console.log(text.replace("&nbsp;", "<span style = 'color: black'>&nbsp;</span>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) para reemplazar todas las apariciones de la cadena en una sola llamada, por ejemplo:

```js
let texto = "&nbsp;hola &nbsp; hola otra vez";
let textoNuevo = texto.replaceAll("&nbsp;", "<span style='color:black'>&nbsp;</span>");
console.log(textoNuevo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Como te han comentado la forma más sencilla es hacerlo con alguna versión de replace. Y en el replace puedes incluir /g para considerar la posibilidad de más de una ocurrencia:

```
"&nbsp;hola &nbsp;hola &nbsp;hola".replace(/&nbsp;/g, "<span style = 'color:black'>&nbsp;</span>");
```